# Wrapped anchor tag around inline-flex container - text not underlined in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox, mozilla

I'm trying to nest an inline-flex container inside an anchor tag (IE11 made me do so). Unfortunately I get different results on FireFox compared to Chrom for example. On Chrom the text remains underlined while FF doesn't bother the draw the line at bottom at all.

Any idea why it works this way?

```css
a{
  color: red;
}

.flex{
  display: inline-flex;
  /* display: flex; */ -> will show the underline
}
```

```html
<a href="www.google.com">
  <div class="flex">Text inside wrapper</div>
</a>
```

Comment: I don't think it is a good way to add `div` inside `a`. You should use `span` and I am using chrome and I don't see the underline: http://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/8fxcyr91/67/

Comment: Do you want the underline to be shown or remove it from chrome also ?

Comment: In HTML5 you can wrap anchors around divs (paragrpahs, sections, etc ..) @Gagandeep Singh I'd like to keep the underline in Firefox as well

Answer (score 1):

If you want the underline to come in firefox as well then just try to change the css for `.flex` to

```css
a{
  color: red;
}

.flex{
  display: inline-flex;
  text-decoration:underline;
  /* display: flex; */ -> will show the underline
}
```

```html
<a href="www.google.com">
  <div class="flex">Text inside wrapper</div>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not answer my question why this happens :)

Comment: This is most probably happening because if you inspect the `<a>` tag in chrome, you can see that chrome is adding its default styles to all the anchor tags with the following rule `a:-webkit-any-link {
    color: -webkit-link;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}` and this is why the inner div shows underline by inheriting the property of underline from the anchor tag, and if you see the same thing in firefox it is not applying any user-agent styles to anchor tag.